# Get data from a dictionary into a mathematic function?

Tags: python, function, loops, nested, python-3.9

I´ve been trying a lot but can´t come to the finsih:

```
sports_info = {"bicycling": {"met": 14,
                         "max_min_of_execution": 60},
            "crunches": {"met": 5,
                         "max_min_of_execution": 15},
            "swimming": {"met": 9.5,
                         "max_min_of_execution": 30},
            "push ups": {"met": 8,
                         "max_min_of_execution": 15},
            "sitting": {"met": 1,
                        "max_min_of_execution": -1}}
```

I want to get the informations from sports_info into the following functions:

```
def met_to_burned_calories_per_minute(met: float, weight: float) -> float:
    return (met * 3.5 * weight)/200

def do_sport_and_burn_calories(calories_to_burn: int, sports_info: dict[str, dict[str, int]],
    weight = float(65)):
    calories_to_burn = 1560
```

and create an output similar to this one:

```
print("To burn <calories_to_burn> calories with your given sports you have to do" 
      "<mins_of_sport_1> mins of <sport_1>, <mins_of_sport_2> mins of <sport_2><mins_of_sport_n> mins of <sport_n>!"
      "At the end you still need to burn <unburned_calories> calories.")
```

I tried different ways to get the sports_info in the given formula, but wasn´t successful,
how can I best start with my code? I thank you for any kind of help in advance!

Comment: can you share your attempt please

Comment: Specifically, can you show how you are trying to use these functions?  For example, `met_to_burned_calories_per_minute` doesn't seem to need anything from `sports_info`, since it only uses the values (`met` and `weight`) passed to it.

Comment: but i have the "met" values in the sports_info dictionary which i have to use

Comment: i don´t know how I can input the met-values from the sports_info into my formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and write your code in a way like so:

```
def do_sport_and_burn_calories(calories_to_burn: int, sports_info: dict[str, dict[str, int]], weight: float):
    print(f'To burn {calories_to_burn} calories with your given sports you have to do')
    todo_list = [f'{sports_info[sport]["max_min_of_execution"]} mins of {sport}' for sport in sports_info]
    todo_results = [met_to_burned_calories_per_minute(sports_info[sport]['met'], weight) for sport in sports_info]
    print(', '.join(todo_list)+'!')
    print(f'At the end you still need to burn {calories_to_burn - sum(todo_results)} calories.')
          
>>> do_sport_and_burn_calories(1560, sports_info, 65)
To burn 1560 calories with your given sports you have to do
60 mins of bicycling, 15 mins of crunches, 30 mins of swimming, 15 mins of push ups, -1 mins of sitting!
At the end you still need to burn 1517.34375 calories.
```

Comment: thanks for your hint and your work! Do you know an other way than f-strings?

Comment: @Flo You could use old fashioned [`str.format`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) but f-strings are more flexible

Comment: oh yes thank you, but isn´t there an other way to get the floats from the dictionary into the formula beside the string-methods?

Comment: @Flo you can use '+' operator but you need care about types in this case: `str(2) + ' times ' + str(2)` will work, `2 + ' times ' + 2` will not.

Comment: ok thanks a lot i will try tomorrow!

Comment: i want that the "max_min_of _execution" of "sitting" is infinite, so that all the rest calories are just decimal numbers, how can i integrate it in your code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by decimal number. Is it something like `round(x, 1)` or `str(round(x,1))`? Python supports [a way](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-infinity/) to type infinities too, you can just use `float("inf")`